# Looking for space travel book from 1970s

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I read the book in the US in the  1970s, I thought it was called "Out There" but can't find it anywhere. It was about a space rocket struggling in some way, had a small crew I think of young people, one was named Ash or Ashley... And either he or one or all of the crew suffered from radiation sickness. I can't remember much more detail but it had a big impact on me as a young teen.

Comment: None of the SF novels on ISFDB titled "Out There" match your description; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=exact&TERM_1=out+there&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: "You have to make it go bang". Pretty much the only part of that story that stuck with me, but it has, although I have no idea why.

Answer (score 19):

This sounds like "[Space Hostages](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1087684.Space_Hostages)" by Nicholas Fisk. It was [first published](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?619561) in 1967, which fits with your recollection of reading it in the 70s. A lieutenant takes control of a space ship and uses it to kidnap a group of children. One of them, a bit of a mummy's boy, was called Ashley. In the take off, the lieutenant overloaded the nuclear-powered motors, and as a consequence received a high radiation dose. He eventually dies of radiation sickness, leaving the children to bring the craft home themselves (with radio guidance from Earth).

Comment: Nice one, how'd you find it?

Comment: @DoscoJones In the dusty corners of my memory  ;)

Comment: Wow, this sounds like it could be the one! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @Briarley !  If it turns out my answer is correct, can you click the check-mark to accept it? That way people will know the question has been answered.